# Is it possible to register a SetChangeListener on a unmodifiable ObservableSet?

Tags: java, set, listener, observablecollection, javafx-8

### Background

In a "plain old" JavaFX desktop application, I have an entity which expose an unmodifiable view of an [`ObservableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ObservableSet.html) like so:

```
public ObservableSet<AbstractMessage> getMessagesUnmodifiable() {
    return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableSet(messages);
}
```

Elsewhere, client code use this API like so:

```
model.getMessagesUnmodifiable()
        .addListener((SetChangeListener<AbstractMessage>) change -> {
            if (change.wasAdded())
                // ... do some work
        });
```

From day 1 (today actually) that I wrote my client code, I immediately felt a bit worrisome. Is it possible to add a listener to a *unmodifiable* Set? If I add a listener, have I not modified the Set then?

### Theory

I've found no documentation on this subject. JavaDoc of [FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableSet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#unmodifiableObservableSet-javafx.collections.ObservableSet-) has one line to say that is irrelevant for this question:

> Creates and returns unmodifiable wrapper on top of provided observable
>   set.

The cousin [FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#unmodifiableObservableMap-javafx.collections.ObservableMap-) has more to say:

> Only mutation operations made to the underlying ObservableMap will be
>   reported to observers that have registered on the unmodifiable
>   instance. **This allows clients to track changes in a Map but disallows
>   the ability to modify it**.

What I marked bold in the quote is exactly what I want to achieve, but using a Set instead of a Map. Since it is possible for unmodifiable and observable maps, I reason it has to work the same for sets too.

### Practice

My client code does not trow an exception. So there's that. But it doesn't work. My listener is never called. It do work If I, just for testing, rewrite the entity's getter method so that he return the modifiable `ObservableSet` reference without sugar on top. So the call to `FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableSet()` clearly break the set's behavior somehow.

I quickly wrote a few lines of code in a separate test application. However, in my test application (a simple `public static void main`) it works like a charm. I rewrote both my test application and my real desktop application so that the code is **absolutely identical** between the two with the following horrifying result: adding a listener to the unmodifiable view does not work in my desktop application, but it work without a flaw in my test application. I cannot explain this finding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set returned from [`FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#unmodifiableObservableSet-javafx.collections.ObservableSet-) work in mysterious ways. You might think you add a listener to the backing set, but in reality, the listeners you add go straight to the wrapper, which has registered himself as a *weak* listener ([`WeakSetChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/WeakSetChangeListener.html)) of the backing set.

As long as the wrapper is alive and kicking, his personal listener will pick up events from the backing set and distribute those to the listeners I have registered with the wrapper. But as I never stored a strong reference to the wrapper, it was only a matter of time before the wrapper was picked up by the garbage collector and disposed thereof. All my trigger-happy listeners joined the ride.

And here lie also the entire difference between my small test application and the desktop application that despite identical code, had two completely different results. My test application was executed from start to finish in no time. It took time though for my desktop application to go from registration of the listener to the actual event. It is during that time a GC kicked in and fucked me up.

After spending my time reading source code only, I must, theoretically, conclude that the unmodifiable yet observable Map work the same. So lesson learned: save the reference to the unmodifiable wrapper or rework your client's API so that client's may pass listeners directly to the backing Set (which is the solution I picked).

For more reading on how weak listeners work in JavaFX, see another answer I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24758987/1268003).